# Display year to date

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to display data for a "Year to Date" range. I need it to show all the dates ranging from the first day of January 2021 until the current date (whatever day today is).

I previously had the data showing only the previous 30 days and had:

```
const today = new Date();
    const startDate =
      this.startDate || new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 30);
    const endDate = this.endDate || today;
```

How can I get the data to show from January 1st, 2021 to whatever the current day is?

Comment: in 2022, will you still want to see data from the first of january 2021? Also, not entirely sure how your two lines of code is working since duplicate `const startDate` should throw errors.

Comment: How can you have two const startDate and what is `this.startDate` - please provide a [mcve] of what you tried in a `[<>]` stacksnippet

Comment: Oops, that was a pasting error. My code is actually:

`const today = new Date();
    const startDate =
      this.startDate || new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 30);
    const endDate = this.endDate || today;`

Comment: @BRAvery—don't put edits in comments, edit the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for every current year

```js
const aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
const end = new Date()
// normalise - otherwise I would see last day of previous year until yesterday due to timezones
end.setHours(15,0,0,0); 
const start = new Date(end.getFullYear(),0,0,15,0,0,0); // 31/12/previous year to get date 0
const days = (end.getTime()-start.getTime())/aDay
let t = start.getTime();
const dates =  [...Array(days)] // create an array of days 
  .map(() => new Date(t+=aDay).toISOString().split('T')[0])

console.log(dates)
```

Using while

```js
const aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
const end = new Date()
// normalise - otherwise I would see last day of previous year until yesterday due to timezones
end.setHours(15,0,0,0); 
const start = new Date(end.getFullYear(),0,0,15,0,0,0); // 31/12/previous year to get date 0
const days = (end.getTime()-start.getTime())/aDay
let t = start.getTime();
const endTime = end.getTime();
const dates = [];
while (t<endTime) {
  dates.push(new Date(t+=aDay).toISOString().split('T')[0])
}

console.log(dates)
```

Comment: The only reason to "normalise" the time is because you're using *toISOString* to generate the timestamp. If you use `date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')` instead you'll get YYYY-MM-DD without the extra cruft. :-) An alternative is to do everything in UTC + *toISOString*. Using a constant for day length is also fraught, but likely doesn't cause any issues with the above (especially not if UTC is used).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create an array `dateArray` of all dates between the first of this year and today:

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

const today = new Date()
const startDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 1);


var dateArray = new Array();
var currentDate = startDate;
while (currentDate <= today) {
  dateArray.push(new Date(currentDate));
  currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
}


console.log(dateArray)
```

Comment: @mplungjan updated for clarity thank you

Comment: This gives me in CET the first date of 31st of december and last day of yesterday, See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026991/295783) why

Comment: @mplungjan—that only happens because the SO console stringifies dates using *toISOString* (or similar) so shows UTC dates, not local.

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, just "better" — IMHO of course. :-)

```js
// Default end is current date
function getDateRange(startDate, endDate = new Date()) {
  // Default start to 1 Jan of endDate year
  if (!startDate) {
    startDate = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), 0);
  // Otherwise copy startDate so don't affect original
  } else {
    startDate = new Date(+startDate);
  }
  let result = [];
  // Push timestamps into an array until endDate
  while (startDate <= endDate) {
    // Push date in YYYY-MM-DD format into result array
    result.push(startDate.toLocaleDateString('en-CA'));
    // Increment startDate
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  
  return result;
}

// Dates from 1 Jan to today
console.log(getDateRange());
```